# How can I fix an iCloud mail SMTP 554 5.7.1 Access Denied error?

Tags: icloud, network, mail.app, email

This on a 15" M2 MBA on MacOS 14.4.1

Just recently I started getting a 554 5.7.1 SMTP error when sending iCloud mail. The Connection Doctor log says:

```
READ Mar 26 04:50:47.891 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:smtp.mail.me.com -- port:587 -- socket:0x60000803dbc0 -- thread:0x6000071109c0
554 5.7.1 <node-17t8.pool-101-51.dynamic.totinternet.net[101.51.221.nnn]>: Client host rejected: Access denied
```

This error message seems to indicate a problem with our external IP address. However, no other machine on the LAN has this problem. iPhones, iPads, other MBAs and an M1 iMac can all send iCloud mail without error. Note that we have a dynamic IP address which changes at least once a day.

The user error message says:

[image: screenshot of user error message]

As you can see, the currently selected server is Google, which is incorrect. For some reason, two iCloud servers are shown. One of them, seemingly at random, will work while the other one will not.

It's kind of a pain to have to go through this every time I send iCloud mail.Mac O

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this myself. I had opened a ticket with Apple Support way back in January. Since then I'd spoken with three different senior support people; none of whom could solve it. All three of them eventually ghosted me and I never heard from them again.

The first hint was when the exact problem appeared for the first time yesterday on my Intel iMac. Same error message in the Connection Doctor log and same symptom of two iCloud servers in the Outgoing Mail accounts list.

Here's what I did:

- Go to Edit SMTP Server list and delete iCloud. Deleting the one there
  deleted both of them in the Outgoing Mail accounts list.
- Turn off iCloud Mail
- Reboot the machine
- Turn on iCloud Mail
- Send mail from my iCloud account. It will tell you that there is no
  Outgoing Mail server, but it will have created one that you can
  select.

Oddly, the iCloud server is shown in the Outgoing Mail server list, but not in the Edit SMTP server list.

This procedure worked on both the MBA and the old iMac.